# Terminating array variable

Tags: powershell

Is there any better way to write this:

```powershell
for($j =0; $j -lt 11; $j++){
    if($averagetime[$j] -ne "no data"){
        Write-host $type[$j] "(" $1st[$j] "):" $averagetime[$j]
    }
}
```

My outptut looks like this: `Multiaxial_Milling ( 5 ): 3.46`

I'd like it to output like this: `Multiaxial_Milling (5): 3.46`

I know `${variable}` works but it does not work for an array. Currently this only a cosmetic issue for me, but I imagine it could be a problem in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the array indexing inside the string with a [sub-expression `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html):

```powershell
Write-host $type[$j] "($($1st[$j])):" $averagetime[$j]
```

PowerShell will evaluate the stuff inside `$(...)` as a normal expression and then replace the `$(...)` with the value returned by this expression.  Below is a demonstration:

```powershell
PS > "$(1 + 1)"
2
PS > "a$(1 + 1)b"
a2b
PS >
```

Note however that sub-expressions only work with double quoted string literals `"..."`.  If you put them inside a single-quoted one `'...'`, they will be treated as normal text.

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know the syntax!

Answer (score 4):

The [format operator](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.using-the-f-format-operator-in-powershell.aspx) is also a good choice in this scenario, especially if you output formatting gets particularly complicated.

Simple example with some basic arrays.

```psh
$evens = 2,4,6,8
$odds = 1,3,5,7

for($j =0; $j -lt 4; $j++){
    Write-Host ("Index {0}: Even - {1} | Odd - {2}" -f $j,$evens[$j],$odds[$j])
}
```

Would net the following output

```
Index 0: Even - 2 | Odd - 1
Index 1: Even - 4 | Odd - 3
Index 2: Even - 6 | Odd - 5
Index 3: Even - 8 | Odd - 7
```

**Note:** We needed to use parentheses here, because otherwise the `-f` would have been picked up as a parameter for `Write-Host`. If you were just sending this to standard output you could omit the `Write-Host` and parentheses.